# Which vim plugin should I use if i want to surround specific text with brackets like this?

Tags: vim

I just want to transform

```
for(int i = 1; i <= N; i++) if(ord[i] == -1) dfs(i, 0, i);
```

to

```
for(int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
    if(ord[i] == -1) dfs(i, 0, i);
}
```

as little key I should press as possible.

I found the plugin 'surround' but It seems like it has some functions(like 'yss{') that surrounds
entire text line with brackets but not the block I want to surround. And if it is possible, i have to add some new lines at some position, so i think it will be so uncomfortable.

And I also found some original vim commands, but I was too long and seems like
taking too much time.

I'll be so glad if you guys tell me which plugin i should use. Thank you!

Comment: are ord and dfs anything to do with vi/vim?!  that looks to me more like java or c# than anything to do with vim the text editor

Comment: ah I see you are talking about adding braces to a for loop. That is far from just "specific text". And what about an if satement you might want to do that one too. By the way off topic somewhat but I think it's clearer and more concise to not have braces when it's just one line.. it's worth learning how to read it when it doesn't. partaicularly with Ifs with many branches.

Answer (score 0):

That can be easily done with the surround.vim plugin: First, you need to make a visual selection of `if(ord[i] == -1) dfs(i, 0, i);` (for example with `f)llv$`), so that the plugin knows what to surround.

The visual mode `gS` command surrounds and places on a new line. For curly braces, that's `gS{`.